# Trouble with packing / unpacking ints to and from char*

Tags: c++, sockets, serialization

I have the following code, which transmits a char* across a UDP socket to a receiver:

```
struct Packet
{
   int seqNum;
   int ackNum;  
   int payloadSize;
   char* payload;
};
--------------------------------------
//MTU = 1460
char* payload = (char*)malloc(MTU);
int bytesCopied = sprintf(payload, "%d%d%d", dataIt->second.seqNum, dataIt->second.ackNum, dataIt->second.payloadSize);
cout << "Bytes Copied: " << bytesCopied << endl;  // prints 3 - thought it would print 12 (3*sizeof(int))?
strcat(payload, dataIt->second.payload);
bytesSent = sendto(mySocket, payload, packetSize, 0,
            (const struct sockaddr *)&toNode,length);
```

The receiver looks like:

```
int n;
char buffer[MTU];
bzero(buffer, MTU);
unsigned int length = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
struct sockaddr_in from;

n = recvfrom(mySocket,buffer,MTU,0,(struct sockaddr *)&from, &length);

if (n < 0) 
    perror("recvfrom");
else
{
    char* seqNum = (char*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    memcpy(seqNum, &buffer, sizeof(int));
    cout << "SeqNum: " << seqNum << endl;
}
```

When I attempt to send 5 bytes of *payload*:  `105#####` -- the receiver outputs: `SeqNum: 105#`. When I send: `1010##########` (10 bytes of payload) the receiver puts: `SeqNum: 1010`. What am I doing wrong?

**Notes:**

- Both are run on the same box (Ubuntu VMs)
- I don't need to worry about portability at all really, for now

**Edit:**

I've tried to also do:

```
memcpy(payload, &dataIt->second.seqNum, sizeof(int));
payload += sizeof(int);
memcpy(payload, &dataIt->second.ackNum, sizeof(int));
payload += sizeof(int);
memcpy(payload, &dataIt->second.payloadSize, sizeof(int));
payload += sizeof(int);
strcat(payload, dataIt->second.payload);
payload -= packetSize; //sizeof(dataIt->second.payload) + sizeof(int) + sizeof(int) + sizeof(int)

bytesSent = sendto(mySocket, payload, packetSize, 0,
(const struct sockaddr *)&toNode,length);
```

But this is wrong, because I'm just corrupting the stream when I run this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re. this code:

```
int bytesCopied = sprintf(payload, "%d%d%d", dataIt->second.seqNum, dataIt->second.ackNum, dataIt->second.payloadSize);
cout << "Bytes Copied: " << bytesCopied << endl;
```

I don't know why you expected `bytesCopied` to be 12. `sizeof(int)` has nothing to do with this; using `sprintf("%d"` causes the int to be converted to base 10 digits. The length could be anywhere from `3` to `30`, or even more if your `int`s are larger than 32-bit.

If you get the result `3` it indicates that all of those integers were in the range `0` through `9`.

This is not a very good data format either, as the other end does not know how to unpack it. Imagine the receiver sees `"12345"`. How does it know whether you sent `12` `34` `5`, or `1` `23` `45` ?

> `bytesSent = sendto(mySocket, payload, packetSize, 0, (const struct sockaddr *)&toNode,length);`

`length` and `packetSize` are not defined anywhere.

```
char* seqNum = (char*)malloc(sizeof(int));
memcpy(seqNum, &buffer, sizeof(int));
cout << "SeqNum: " << seqNum << endl;
```

Passing a `char *` to `cout` like this means that it expects a null-terminated string. However , (if `buffer` actually contained a packed int) you are sending it four bytes that do not form a string.

Is this code supposed to unpack the data you wrote in with `sprintf`? Because if so, it doesn't. You seem very mixed up on the difference between an `int`, and the base 10 representation of that int.

Comment: Ahhh, you're very right - I was confusing the two. Do you have a suggestion for how I could better pack my `int`s so that I can reliably unpack them at the receiver?

Comment: `memcpy` them in and `memcpy` them out (if you're not worried about portability)

Comment: Hmm, so I tried that but it seems to have corrupt the `char*`... I've updated my question with what I tried.

Comment: stop doing `strcat` and other string functions, you are not forming a string here

Comment: So I have it working for the ints - but I can't get the location of `payload` right to output the `char*` portion of the stream (i.e., `dataIt->second.payload`): `memcpy(payload, dataIt->second.payload, sizeof(dataIt->second.payload)); ---- payload -= sizeof(dataIt->second.payload); ---- cout << "payload: " << payload << endl;` prints an empty string..

Comment: it's not a string, you can't `cout` it.